# Can I convert a cheque to money in any bank? Is there a fee?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, check, online-banking, refund

After a Ryanair flight cancellation and several e-mails, they've sent a cheque.

Well, I have no physical bank account in UK and have no idea how to claim money from a cheque. Plus, I suspect I will have to pay a fee to do it if I go in a bank.

[Assuming I don't find a way to force Ryanair to pay me with a transfer on my Revolut account](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162365/ryanair-sent-cheque-instead-of-sending-money-to-debt-card-with-which-i-payed-c), how can I convert the cheque in money?

- Can I go to any physical bank?
- Will I have to pay a fee? How much is it, usually?

Comment: What bank/country is the cheque issued from?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, _NatWest_ is written on the cheque.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Will a British bank accept a twice-endorsed cheque?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/66209/14319) Alternatively, if you have some form of UK ID, perhaps you can convert the cheque to cash at NatWest. Note that in the USA a tax id is required to cash at teller, UK may be similar.

Comment: Please add a country tag.

Comment: This is why everyone should have a bank account with a branch that is local to you.  Fintech is great, until you need something that only a bank can do.

Comment: @RonJohn, well, I wonder why an airline which I gave money to via a channel want to make refunds through another channel. By the way, the have already refunded other flights to me in the past, and they did so on my Revolut card. Now they're doing differently, and the reason is apparent. Discourage me and making me give up and leave the money to them. This is close to criminal, imho.

Comment: " I wonder why an airline ... refunds through another channel." That is a complete **separate** (but good, though probably not authoritatively answerable) **question**.

Comment: @RonJohn, [here's the question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135906/ryanair-sent-cheque-instead-of-transfering-money-to-the-revolut-account-i-used-t), which I had initially posted travel.stackexchange, as I didn't know of money.stackexchange.